# jQuery switch class to change css background

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a web page that shows photos full screen and want to offer users to the ability to switch the background color between black and white using a simple set of links:

```
<ul id="switch">
    <li id="white" class="current">White</li>
    <li id="black">Black</li>
</ul>

body.white { background: #f0f0f0 url('white.png'); }
body.black { background: #222222 url('black.png'); }
```

The plan is to show which one is currently selected using a class of current and when clicked will fade in and out the different color scheme. can anyone help?

**EDIT: Just to confirm I want to switch the class on the body and not just change the CSS of background color.**

Thanks

Comment: you want an *animated* background color change, or just change the background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use classes instead of just changing css...

```
$('#switch li').click(function(){
  $('body').removeClass('white black').addClass(this.id);
  $('#switch li').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
$('#switch li').click(function(){
  $('body').css('background', this.id);
  $('#switch li').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Above code applies background color to `body` (you can replace if element is some other one) when an `li` is clicked (you can use **links** instead). Also the `current` class is removed from all `lis` and then applied to clicked one.

Comment: How would I change the class of the body though?

Comment: More elegant solution here. Why do you need to change the class of the body? What would that accomplish?

Comment: because I have a background texture as well

Comment: @Cameron: Notice the line in my answer: `$('body').css('background', this.id);` Also make sure to wrap your code in jquery ready handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#white").click(function() {
    $("body").css("background", "white")
});

$("#black").click(function() {
    $("body").css("background", "black")
});
```

Comment: Your elegant solution does not take care of current class. Also no need to assign two click handlers, one can be used.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually an easier way than having two different lis.

For whatever your background element (#back) is, on clicking something with an id of "switch":

```
$('#switch').click(function() {
  a = $('#back').css('background');
  if (a == 'black') {
  $('#back').css('background','white');
  }
  else {
  $('#back').css('background','black');
  }
});
```